# 'Error: Duplicate resources' after updating Google Open Source Notices to 0.9.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I've updated `com.google.gms:oss-licenses` to version 0.9.2 and now Android Studio gives me the following error when building my project:

```
[raw/third_party_license_metadata] /Users/<name>/AndroidStudioProjects/<project>/app/build/generated/third_party_licenses/res/raw/third_party_license_metadata  [raw/third_party_license_metadata] /Users/<name>/AndroidStudioProjects/<project>/app/src/main/res/raw/third_party_license_metadata: Error: Duplicate resources
[raw/third_party_licenses] /Users/<name>/AndroidStudioProjects/<project>/app/build/generated/third_party_licenses/res/raw/third_party_licenses  [raw/third_party_licenses] /Users/<name>/AndroidStudioProjects/<project>/app/src/main/res/raw/third_party_licenses: Error: Duplicate resources
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Google Open Source Licenses Notices plugin changed the path where those 2 files are saved.
(`third_party_license_metadata` and `third_party_license`)

Old:
`<project-root>/app/src/main/res/raw/`

New:
`<project-root>/app/build/generated/third_party_licenses/res/raw/`

You can safely delete these 2 files in the old folder.